# Rails Spree: не выполняется bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, bundler

Следуя инструкциям выполняю bundle install, получаю ошибку:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree.git
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...Killed
```

Без этих гемов всё остальное ставится:

```
gem "spree", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree"
gem "spree_gateway", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway"
gem "spree_auth_devise", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise"
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Бандлер не даёт поставить гемы из под рута, всё верно.

Создайте пользователя и установите им менеджер версий руби, например [rvm](https://rvm.io/).

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Установите зависимости

```
rvm requirements
```

Теперь можно ставить гемы.